# Where does Internet Explorer store its' add-ons?

Tags: internet-explorer, add-on

I have checked all around the registry and I could not find any lists of all installed extensions.

At this point, any general location of IE extensions/add-ons would help.

Comment: [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) could also help tracking IE extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.systemlookup.com/learn.php):

**Browser Helper Objects** - Browser plug-ins which are designed to enhance the browser's functionality.
Entries can be found in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```

**Toolbars** - Additional toolbars that appear in a browser, often below the address bar.
Entries can be found in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
```

**URLSearchHooks** - Used when an address without a protocol such as http:// has been entered in the browser's address bar.
Entries can be found in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\URLSearchHooks
```

**Explorer Bars** - Internet Explorer sidebars located adjacent to the browser pane.
Entries can be found in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars
```

Additionally, **custom items for context menu**:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\<Menu Text>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\<Menu Text>
```

**Custom items for Tools menu, custom toolbar buttons**:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\{GUID}
```

[More info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions
```

Comment: I was already aware of that registry location, but only 3 out my 13 installed add-ons show up.

Comment: What about HKCU have you looked there?

Comment: Just looked, there is no Extensions directory under Internet Explorer when under HKCU.

Answer (score 0):

I found mine at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```

I'm on Windows 8.1