# How does navigator.plugins find and return an array of plugin objects installed on a web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Does it query a location locally on the hard drive, in the browser's install directory?  Is there a registry key where they are stored? Is there some other config file with a plugin list?  I'm sure there may be differences between IE, Chrome, and FireFox, so feel free to let me know...

Are plugins pulled once when the browser is launched and cached, or does every call to navigator.plugins perform another plugin query?

Just trying to get a picture as to how the navigator.plugins function works.  Any info will be helpful.

Comment: Since Javascript is run by the browser, and it's up to the browser to how each function is implemented, the browser just returns it's internal plugin list in response to `navigator.plugins`.

Comment: What is the source of your concern? That is, why would it matter how the browser does it?

Comment: Jaxo - how do I see how each browser handles the navigator.plugins request?
@Pointy - I'm seeing some differences from browser to browser, and want to get a better understanding of the differences in functionality

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this before as well and came up empty. It appears that IE may store them in the registry: [Where does Internet Explorer store its' add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036814/where-does-internet-explorer-store-its-add-ons)

Not sure where the internal plugin list is located for chrome/firefox but it has to be stored somewhere.